# CodeDom Black Box

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

VB.Net Code. I want to hide the black box that opens up with a compiled code... how?

It opens a cmd shell whenever I compile it...

```
    Public Shared Function CompileVBCode(sourceFile As String, exeFile As String) As Boolean
    Dim vbprovider As VBCodeProvider = New VBCodeProvider()
    Dim cp As New CompilerParameters()
    cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
    cp.GenerateInMemory = False
    cp.GenerateExecutable = True
    cp.OutputAssembly = exeFile
    Dim cr As CompilerResults = vbprovider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sourceFile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cp.CompilerOptions += "/t:winexe"
```

Comment: You should explain what this is doing